# How to create comma separated list as the argument of a macro or command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach, comma-separated-list

In the following MWE, I tried to create a command (but I also tried with a macro) that receives `#1` argument. In this case, I am trying to create a comma separated list. However, as shown in the figure below, it seems that the argument works as just one element `\x` of the list when I call it via `\printKW`, as if the commas weren't actual commas. **How do I create a command (or macro) that stores a comma separated list and how can I call it via another command (or macro)?.** Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}

\newcommand\KeyWords[1]{\def\@KeyWords{#1}}
\newcommand\printKW{\@KeyWords}

\newcommand{\kwmacro}{Letter, Word, Phrase, Paragraph, Page, Book, Library}

\KeyWords{Letter, Word, Phrase, Paragraph, Page, Book, Library}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Comprehensive knowledge storage follows the evolutionary sequence given by}
\foreach \x [count=\n] in \kwmacro {(\n) \x, }
\textbf{while the access to it follows the reverse order.}

\textbf{Keywords:}
\foreach \x [count=\n] in \printKW {\n.~\x. }

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not obvious what you want to do with the comma separated argument. If you want only save it, use `\def`. If you want to process all comma separated arguments by your own macro, I can show you how to do it. Or you want to cooperate comma separated lists with pgf macros like in your example? Why do you want to insert `\printKW` in the context of `\foreach`? You can use directly `\kwmacro` as shown above in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros in PGF foreach loops are only expanded once but `\printKW` needs two steps to expand to the list.  The can be fixed for all instances of the foreach loop by patching the internal macros.  Here I introduce a check whether the macro is expandable and if it is perform a full expansion (expl3 `f`-type) on it.

You also want `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` around you definition, otherwise you are overriding the definition of `\@` which might lead to mysterious errors later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfutil@ifexpandable#1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\noexpand#1#1%
        \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\pgffor@macro@list#1{%
    \pgfutil@ifexpandable#1%
        {\expandafter\pgffor@normal@list\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}}%
        {\expandafter\pgffor@normal@list\expandafter{#1}}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\KeyWords[1]{\def\@KeyWords{#1}}
\newcommand\printKW{\@KeyWords}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\kwmacro}{Letter, Word, Phrase, Paragraph, Page, Book, Library}

\KeyWords{Letter, Word, Phrase, Paragraph, Page, Book, Library}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Comprehensive knowledge storage follows the evolutionary sequence given by}
\foreach \x [count=\n] in \kwmacro {(\n) \x, }
\textbf{while the access to it follows the reverse order.}

\textbf{Keywords:}
\foreach \x [count=\n] in \printKW {\n.~\x. }

\end{document}
```

Probably it even makes sense to just scrap the expandability check and just use

```
\def\pgffor@macro@list#1{%
    \expandafter\pgffor@normal@list\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}}
```